# progress bar in `knitr` 1.43

Tags: progress-bar, knitr

After updating the `knitr` package to version 1.43, I get very lengthy progress report that doesn't look good. Here is an excerpt:

```
processing file: file.Rmd
1/115                                   
2/115 [unnamed-chunk-1]                 
3/115                                   
4/115 [unnamed-chunk-2]                 
5/115                                   
6/115 [unnamed-chunk-3]                 
7/115                                   
8/115 [unnamed-chunk-4]                 
9/115                                   
10/115 [introduction]                    
  |..............................               |  67% [literature-load-tables]

processing file: ./_00-introduction.Rmd
                                                                                                                   
11/115                                   
12/115 [unemp-plot]          
13/115                                   
14/115 [data-load]                       
15/115                                   
16/115 [data-summary-prepare]            
17/115
```

Previously, I used to get dynamically updating progress bar. I cannot reproduce it anymore since I already have the updated version of `knitr`, but it looked similar to `tqdm` in python.

I read there are package options that control the look of the progress bar. So, I set `options(knitr.progress.simple = FALSE)` in my Rmd file. That did nothing. I added `options(knitr.package.verbose = FALSE)`, which again changed nothing in the progress report.

Any ideas how I can bring back the dynamically updating simple progress bar?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you knit the document?

Answer (score 0):

The options need to be set in your `.Rprofile` or before you knit the document (via `knitr::knit()` or `rmarkdown::render()`). It is too late to set them inside the Rmd document.